# How to split string and get data in sql Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have created 1 table and there is 1 column named `data` . In data field i am getting data like:

```
{"ip":"xxx.xx.xx.xxx","power":"7.15","sat":"10","status":"ok"}

{"ip":"xxx.xx.xx.xxx","power":"7.15","sat":"10","capacity":"20","status":"ok"}

{"ip":"xxx.xx.xx.xxx","power":"7.15","sat":"10","status":"ok"}

{"ip":"xxx.xx.xx.xxx","power":"7.15","sat":"10","capacity":"20","status":"ok"}
```

Now i have created 1 trigger in which i am getting this data. now i want to split data and want to get value of `capacity` .

This `capacity` position is not fixed and may be sometime it will not come with data.

So how can i split and get value of `capacity` ? .I have SQL SERVER 2008.

Comment: I would suggest to rethink the way you store and query your data.

Comment: i cant change how the data is stored !!! Database have more than 6 GB data. !! so have to do it like this way only !!

Comment: 6GB is cents. This is a really not a good design for database and will cause issues in a development.

Comment: Yes i know its not good but i havent design this !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have `Data` table like this

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    data varchar(200)
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
(
    data
)
VALUES
('"ip":"xxx.xx.xx.xxx","power":"7.15","sat":"10","status":"ok"'),
('"ip":"xxx.xx.xx.xxx","power":"7.15","sat":"10","capacity":"20","status":"ok"'),
('"ip":"xxx.xx.xx.xxx","power":"7.15","sat":"10","status":"ok"'),
('"ip":"xxx.xx.xx.xxx","power":"7.15","sat":"10","capacity":"20","status":"ok"')
```

You could use a string split function and `outer apply` like this

```
Select sd.data, replace(replace(c.value, '"', ''),'capacity:','') AS Capacity
FROM @SampleData sd
OUTER APPLY
(   SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[SplitString](sd.data,',') c
    WHERE c.Value LIKE '%capacity%'
) c
```

Return

```
data                                                                Capacity
"ip":"xxx.xx.xx.xxx","power":"7.15","sat":"10","status":"ok"        NULL
"ip":"xxx.xx.xx.xxx","power":"7.15","sat":"10","capacity":"20","status":"ok"    20
"ip":"xxx.xx.xx.xxx","power":"7.15","sat":"10","status":"ok"         NULL
"ip":"xxx.xx.xx.xxx","power":"7.15","sat":"10","capacity":"20","status":"ok"    20
```

Here's string split function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString] (@Text varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
   Select Pos = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
        ,Value = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
   From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@Text,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
   Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for troubles, I'm little bit sleepy.
Check this:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: i am using SQL SERVER !!

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/ (sorry)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the capacity values there really is no much point of splitting the data when you can simply extract the capacity values from the string:

Using the sample data from TriV's answer, you can do this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT RIGHT(data, LEN(data) - PATINDEX('%,"capacity":%', data) - 11) As data
    FROM @SampleData  
    WHERE data LIKE '%,"capacity":%'
)

SELECT LEFT(data, PATINDEX('%","%', data)) As Capacity
FROM CTE
```

Results:

```
Capacity
"20"
"20"
```

[See a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/JGKX64255)